# scroll google doc with google app script

Tags: scroll, google-apps-script, google-docs

Is it possible to scroll a google doc using google app script?

I have an app script that searches for all headers in an active doc and creates a table of contents, and now I'd like to link the contents list to the headers as they occur in the doc itself.

I've made this work using jquery in the mozilla rich text editor and it's very handy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible now with setSelection() method

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#setselectionrange

There is also NamedRange entity that we can create on a document for later retrieval

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately it's not currently possible to control the scroll or cursor position within a document. See our support page for information on how to file feature requests: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support

Comment: There is a setCursor(position) method now that maybe didn't exist back in 2013: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#setCursor(Position)

Comment: But actually I don't see any way to create a Position from an arbitrary integer offset.  :-/  getCursor() is the only way I'm seeing to get one.